# Python - Assigning Multiple Keys for a Single Value

Tags: python, dictionary, key, range, key-value

I'd like to be able to assign the following keys to these values in Python:

- Numbers 01 - 10 : `5.01`
- Numbers 11 - 20 : `7.02`
- Numbers 21 - 30 : `9.03`
- Numbers 31 - 40 : `11.04`
- Numbers 41 - 50 : `15.00`
- Numbers 51 - 60 : `17.08`
- Numbers 61 - 70 : `19.15`

I know that this is possible:

```
rates = dict.fromkeys(range(1, 11), 5.01)
rates.update(dict.fromkeys(range(11, 21), 7.02)
# ...etc
```

and that's okay. However, is there a way to do this in one line or one initializer list in Python?

Comment: That is a good question. I am also curious to know the one line for this code. To answer your question in the first place, this is possible. Python community claims that there's a one line answer for any statement in Python.

Comment: @Andy: I think you misunderstood *There should be one obvious way to do something*; that does **not** mean that there are one-liners for everything. It just means that Python tries to give you clear syntax and not a plethora of ways to do the same thing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that is exactly what I was trying to say,but in different words. Please excuse my English.

Comment: I guess by one line you meant one or more lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension and an initial mapping:

```
numbers = {1: 5.01, 11: 7.02, 21: 9.03, 31: 11.04, 41: 15.0, 51: 71.08, 61: 19.15}
numbers = {k: v for start, v in numbers.items() for k in range(start, start + 10)}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> numbers = {1: 5.01, 11: 7.02, 21: 9.03, 31: 11.04, 41: 15.0, 51: 71.08, 61: 19.15}
>>> numbers = {k: v for start, v in numbers.items() for k in range(start, start + 10)}
>>> pprint(numbers)
{1: 5.01,
 2: 5.01,
 3: 5.01,
 4: 5.01,
 5: 5.01,
 6: 5.01,
 7: 5.01,
 8: 5.01,
 9: 5.01,
 10: 5.01,
 11: 7.02,
 12: 7.02,
 13: 7.02,
 14: 7.02,
 15: 7.02,
 16: 7.02,
 17: 7.02,
 18: 7.02,
 19: 7.02,
 20: 7.02,
 21: 9.03,
 22: 9.03,
 23: 9.03,
 24: 9.03,
 25: 9.03,
 26: 9.03,
 27: 9.03,
 28: 9.03,
 29: 9.03,
 30: 9.03,
 31: 11.04,
 32: 11.04,
 33: 11.04,
 34: 11.04,
 35: 11.04,
 36: 11.04,
 37: 11.04,
 38: 11.04,
 39: 11.04,
 40: 11.04,
 41: 15.0,
 42: 15.0,
 43: 15.0,
 44: 15.0,
 45: 15.0,
 46: 15.0,
 47: 15.0,
 48: 15.0,
 49: 15.0,
 50: 15.0,
 51: 71.08,
 52: 71.08,
 53: 71.08,
 54: 71.08,
 55: 71.08,
 56: 71.08,
 57: 71.08,
 58: 71.08,
 59: 71.08,
 60: 71.08,
 61: 19.15,
 62: 19.15,
 63: 19.15,
 64: 19.15,
 65: 19.15,
 66: 19.15,
 67: 19.15,
 68: 19.15,
 69: 19.15,
 70: 19.15}
```

The dictionary expression produces both a key and a value for each iteration of the loops. There are two loops in that expression, and you need to read them from left to right as nested in that order. Written out as a non-comprehension set of loops, you'd get:

```
numbers = {1: 5.01, 11: 7.02, 21: 9.03, 31: 11.04, 41: 15.0, 51: 71.08, 61: 19.15}
output = {}
# loop over the (key, value) pairs in the numbers dictionary
for start, v in numbers.items():
    for k in range(start, start + 10):
        output[k] = v
numbers = output
```

Essentially the keys in the original `numbers` dictionary are turned into ranges to form 10 new keys in the output dictionary, all with the same value.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Never would've thought to do a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the syntax here a bit more? I'm still trying to wrap my head around how this works. Thanks.

Comment: @homersimpson: I added an expanded version of the dictionary comprehension for you, does that make it clearer?

Comment: @martigin-pieters: Yes! Thank you for that - it is very helpful. I had no idea you could have nested loops inside comprehensions.